# Errors when installing substrate-validator-set

Tags: substrate

I'm trying to install the substrate-validator-set pallet but I'm getting this errors:
I'm trying to modify it to work but I can't get it working, I make a fork and tried to compile but it give me a bunch of errors, something like "expected `,`" ex:

```
error: expected `,`
   --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:639:39
    |
639 |         #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = Atomics, catch)]
    |                                       ^^^^^^^

error: expected `,`
    --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:1576:39
     |
1576 |         #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = Math)]
     |                                       ^^^^

error: expected `,`
    --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:2832:39
     |
2832 |         #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = Reflect, js_name = getOwnPropertyDescriptor, catch)]
     |                                       ^^^^^^^

error[E0425]: cannot find function `get` in module `Reflect`
    --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:1524:28
     |
1524 |     let iter_fn = Reflect::get(val, iter_sym.as_ref())?;
     |                            ^^^ not found in `Reflect`
     |
help: consider importing this function
     |
21   | use std::rt::panic_count::get;
     |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Memory` in module `WebAssembly`
    --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:4933:60
     |
4933 |                   let mem = buf.unchecked_ref::<WebAssembly::Memory>();
     |                                                              ^^^^^^ not found in `WebAssembly`
...
5008 | / arrays! {
5009 | |     /// `Int8Array()`
5010 | |     /// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array
5011 | |     Int8Array: i8,
...    |
5043 | |     Float64Array: f64,
5044 | | }
     | |_- in this macro invocation
     |
     = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Memory` in module `WebAssembly`
    --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:4958:60
     |
4958 |                   let mem = buf.unchecked_ref::<WebAssembly::Memory>();
     |                                                              ^^^^^^ not found in `WebAssembly`
...
5008 | / arrays! {
5009 | |     /// `Int8Array()`
5010 | |     /// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array
5011 | |     Int8Array: i8,
...    |
5043 | |     Float64Array: f64,
5044 | | }
     | |_- in this macro invocation
     |
     = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Memory` in module `WebAssembly`
    --> /home/easy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/js-sys-0.3.47/src/lib.rs:4968:60
     |
4968 |                   let mem = buf.unchecked_ref::<WebAssembly::Memory>();
     |                                                              ^^^^^^ not found in `WebAssembly`
...
5008 | / arrays! {
5009 | |     /// `Int8Array()`
5010 | |     /// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array
5011 | |     Int8Array: i8,
...    |
5043 | |     Float64Array: f64,
5044 | | }
     | |_- in this macro invocation
     |
     = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to 123 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0412, E0425.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `js-sys`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try update wasm-bindgen (cargo update -p wasm-bindgen)